# Find the first n prime numbers and store them in an array

Tags: java, math, primes, algebra

I need to find the first `n` *prime numbers* and store them in the array `primes`. With the help of stuff I found on stackoverflow I succeeded in find the first `n` numbers, but when I try to store them in the array, I get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`...

```java
public static int[] firstNPrimes(int n) {
    int[] primes = new int[n];
    int ncounter = 0;
    int isPrime = 2;
    for (int i = 0; ncounter < n; i++) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < isPrime; j++) {
            if (isPrime % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            primes[i] = isPrime;
            ncounter++;
        }
        isPrime++;
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you use a different name for the variable `isPrime`. When a variable starts with `is` (or `has`, `are`, etc...) it suggests it is a `boolean`, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with `primes[i] = isPrime;` it should be `primes[ncounter] = isPrime;`

You don't need `i` variable at all, use while loop instead:

```java
public static int[] firstNPrimes(int n) {
    int[] primes = new int[n];
    int ncounter = 0;
    int isPrime = 2;
    while (ncounter < n) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < isPrime; j++) {
            if (isPrime % j == 0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime) {
            primes[ncounter] = isPrime;
            ncounter++;
        }
        isPrime++;
    }
    return primes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
primes[i] = isPrime;
```

by

```
primes[ncounter] = isPrime;
```

This counter increments only when you put an element in the array, whereas, the variable `i` keeps on increasing and can also become greater than `n` since there is no condition on its limit in the for loop.

Comment: still gives me an ArrayOutOfBoundEsception 10 ... I will try to use a while loop instead as someone suggested below

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong index for your primes array.
Change this code:

```java
if (prime) {
    primes[i] = isPrime;
    ncounter++;
}
```

to this:

```java
if (prime) {
    primes[ncounter] = isPrime;
    ncounter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you have fixed the size of array to be `n`. And you are storing the found prime at `i`th index, but the `i` can exceed the value of `n`, thats why you are getting array out of bounds exception.

Replace

```java
primes[i] = isPrime
```

with

```java
primes[ncounter] = isPrime
```

Answer (score 0):

In your initial solution, you were updating the counter i regardless if you found a new prime. This causes it to get ahead of the max size of the array. You can just use the ncounter variable and a while loop like so:

```
public static int[] firstNPrimes (int n) {
    int[] primes = new int[n];
    int ncounter = 0;
    int isPrime = 2;

    while (ncounter < n) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (int j=2; j<isPrime; j++){
            if (isPrime%j ==0){
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime){
            primes[ncounter] = isPrime;
            ncounter++;
        }
        isPrime++;
    }

    return primes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A *prime number* is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a *product* of two smaller natural numbers.

Using *Java 8* you can find these numbers as follows:

```java
int n = 10;
int[] primes = IntStream
        // infinite sequential ordered IntStream
        // starting at 2 in increments of 1
        .iterate(2, i -> i + 1)
        // filter prime numbers
        .filter(i -> IntStream
                // numbers from 2 to current number
                .range(2, i)
                // do not divide the current
                // number without a remainder
                .allMatch(j -> i % j != 0))
        // first 'n' prime numbers
        .limit(n)
        // return an array
        .toArray();

// output
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primes));
// [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```